# Show less categories (list items) in mobile and medium devices

Tags: css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code to show a menu with categories.

```
  <div class=" d-md-block">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col p-0 m-0">
                    <ul class="Categories__Menu">
                        @foreach($categories->take(6) as $category)
                            <li class="">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" name="category" id="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</a>
                            </li>
                        @endforeach

                        <li><a  data-toggle="modal" id="showCategories" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg" href="">More <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But do you know how to in small devices instead of show 6 categories show only 2 list items? And in medium devices instead of show 6 categories show only 3 list items?

Comment: are you using bootstrap at all?  If yes : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/

Comment: Thanks, but the categories are in a loop, do you know how to dispay only the first two categories in mobile devices and 3 in medium devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution with medium 1020px and small 768px, but you should change them for your needs:

```
    @media ( max-width: 1020px) { 
         .Categories__Menu > li:nth-child(n+3) {
             display: none;
         }
    }

    @media ( max-width: 768px) { 
         .Categories__Menu > li:nth-child(n+2) {
             display: none;
         }
    }
```

In :nth-child() you can use maths expressions with n, like -3n+2, and it will be calculated from n=0.

Comment: Thanks, but do you know how to show in all media queries the list item "                        <li><a  data-toggle="modal" id="showCategories" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg" href="">More <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
"?

Comment: Then you should give a class name to all of list items in the loop and instead of li tag you can use there the class name and the last li wont be hidden because it doesnt have that class name, so: 
@media ( max-width: 1020px) { 
         .Categories__Menu > .list-item--hidden:nth-child(n+3) {
             display: none;
         }
    }

Answer (score 0):

> You can do it by media queries .You just have to select a correct
>   break point for the devices
>   something like this .

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .ullist li:nth-child(3) {
                display: none
            }
            .ullist li:nth-child(4) {
                display: none
            }
            .ullist li:nth-child(5) {
                display: none
            }
            .ullist li:nth-child(6) {
                display: none
            }

        }

<ul class="ullist">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>

</ul>
```

the above code will display all six list on device width more then 600 and hide the last four on small device . So as per your need you can choose the break point and use this code.

> If you want you can loop the all li in scss. Here is how to use for
>   loop in css

http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while

Comment: Thanks, but the categories are in a loop, do you know how to dispay only the first two categories in mobile devices and 3 in medium devices?